# combinations groups question

Tags: combinatorics

I have 25 people who will be split in to groups of 5 people each day over 5 days. Can I rotate them so they all meet each other only once? Help!
Sorry forgot to mention they all meet in 5 different locations

Comment: It's a variation of Kirkman's schoolgirl problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem

Answer (score 0):

It is even possible to divide them across 6 days

Day 1:

Group 1: 1,2,3,4,5

Group 2: 6,7,8,9,10

Group 3: 11,12,13,14,15

Group 4: 16,17,18,19,20

Group 5: 21,22,23,24,25

Day 2:

Group 1: 1,6,11,16,21

Group 2: 2,7,12,17,22

Group 3: 3,8,13,18,23

Group 4: 4,9,14,19,24

Group 5: 5,10,15,20,25

3:

Group 1: 1,7,13,19,25

Group 2: 2,8,14,20,21

Group 3: 3,9,15,16,22

Group 4: 4,10,11,17,23

Group 5: 5,6,12,18,24

Day 4:

Group 1: 1,8,15,17,24

Group 2: 2,9,11,18,25

Group 3: 3,10,12,19,21

Group 4: 4,6,13,20,22

Group 5: 5,7,14,16,23

Day 5:

Group 1: 1,9,12,20,23

Group 2: 2,10,13,16,24

Group 3: 3,6,14,17,25

Group 4: 4,7,15,18,21

Group 5: 5,8,11,19,22

Day 6:

Group 1: 1,10,14,18,22

Group 2: 2,6,15,19,23

Group 3: 3,7,11,20,24

Group 4: 4,8,12,16,25

Group 5: 5,9,13,17,21