# combinations of 5 groups question

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I have $25$ people who will be split into groups of $5$ people each day over $5$ days in $5$ different locations. Can I rotate them so that they all meet each other only once and visit each location only once over the $5$ days?

Comment: again${}{}{}{}{}$? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391843/combinations-groups-question

Comment: If these two questions are exact duplicates, why do they have different answers?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the groups on day $1$ are $A,B,C,D,E$ visiting venues $1,2,3,4,5$ respectively

Consider the venues visited by the members of group $A$ on day $2$. They've all visited venue $1$ already, so there are five people visiting four venues. Two of them must visit the same venue on day $2$ if they are not to repeat venues. And that contradicts the conditions in the problem.